# WIX - Insufficient Privileges Uninstalling Service

Tags: c#, service, wix, wix3

I'm building an install package for a Windows Service using WIX installer. I'm can create the install package and it installs and starts the service with an issue but I'm unable to uninstall the service. The error in the uninstall log is is:

```
MSI (s) (E4:E4) [11:51:15:117]: Error: 1060. Failed to change configuration of service Service Name because handle to the service could be obtained. Check if the service exists on the system.
```

followed by:

```
MSI (s) (E4:E4) [11:51:18:900]: Product: Service Name -- Error 1939. Service '' (Service Name) could not be configured.  This could be a problem with the package or your permissions. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to configure system services.
```

which is the displayed error.

[image]

Here is the component configuration in my Product.wxs.

```
<Component Id="$(var.TestImportService.TargetFileName)" Guid="7BCCB287-D4A5-42B9-B83B-E67E22D56D90">        
        <File Id="$(var.TestImportService.TargetFileName)" Name="$(var.TestImportService.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.TestImportService.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
        <!-- Remove all files from the INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
        <RemoveFile Id="ALLFILES" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />
        <!-- Tell WiX to install the Service -->
        <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                        Name="$(var.Name)"
                        Type="ownProcess"
                        DisplayName="$(var.Name)"
                        Description="The description."
                        Interactive="no"
                        Arguments="-start"
                        Vital="yes"
                        Start="auto"
                        ErrorControl="normal">
          <util:PermissionEx User="LocalSystem"
                             GenericAll="yes"
                             ServiceChangeConfig="yes"
                             ServiceEnumerateDependents="yes"
                             ChangePermission="yes"
                             ServiceInterrogate="yes"
                             ServicePauseContinue="yes"
                             ServiceQueryConfig="yes"
                             ServiceQueryStatus="yes"
                             ServiceStart="yes"
                             ServiceStop="yes" />
        </ServiceInstall>
        <!-- Tell WiX to start the Service -->
        <ServiceControl Id="ServiceInstaller" Name="$(var.Name)" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" />
        <ServiceConfig ServiceName="$(var.Name)" DelayedAutoStart="1" PreShutdownDelay="5000" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall="yes" OnUninstall="yes" />
      </Component>
```

The account I log in to the machine with is in the machine's administrators group. What have I not set up correctly to get the uninstall to work?

EDIT:
As requested, I ran the installer with verbose logging. Here are the command line's that I found in the logs.

```
From Install Log
MSI (c) (48:44) [13:44:13:945]: Command Line: CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Users\user.name\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\TestService\TestServiceSetup\bin\Debug CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=14664 

...

MSI (s) (DC:4C) [13:44:45:191]: Command Line: INSTALLFOLDER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Company Name\Test Service\ ROOTDIRECTORY=C:\Program Files (x86)\Company Name\ TARGETDIR=C:\ CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Users\user.name\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\TestService\TestServiceSetup\bin\Debug CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=14664 USERNAME=Information Technology COMPANYNAME=Company Name SOURCEDIR=C:\Users\user.name\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\TestService\TestServiceSetup\bin\Debug\ ACTION=INSTALL EXECUTEACTION=INSTALL ROOTDRIVE=C:\ INSTALLLEVEL=1 SECONDSEQUENCE=1 ADDLOCAL=MainApplication ACTION=INSTALL 


From Uninstall Log
MSI (s) (9C:F4) [13:55:40:179]: Command Line: REMOVE=ALL CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Users\user.name\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\TestService\TestServiceSetup\bin\Debug CLIENTUILEVEL=2 CLIENTPROCESSID=5000
```

Comment: Does the service exist in services.msc, before install? At time of error?

This could help point to a permission error or coding error.

Comment: Yes, the service installs correctly, shows in the services control panel and runs, it's just that I can't uninstall it because of the permissions error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wix Installer : verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983392/wix-installer-verify-that-you-have-sufficient-privileges-to-install-system-ser)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not able to find the service during uninstall and looking at your WXS:

```
<ServiceControl Id="ServiceInstaller" Name="$(var.Name)" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" />
```

You are asking your installer to delete the service on both install and uninstall. Hence the installer cant find the service to be removed, can you please change that to and try again:

```
<ServiceControl Id="ServiceInstaller" Name="$(var.Name)" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" />
```

*Remove - Specifies whether the service should be removed by the DeleteServices action on install, uninstall or both. For 'install', the service will be removed only when the parent component is being installed (msiInstallStateLocal or msiInstallStateSource); for 'uninstall', the service will be removed only when the parent component is being removed (msiInstallStateAbsent); for 'both', the service will be removed in both cases.*

[ServiceControl](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html)

Comment: Thanks @Isaiah4110, I changed Remove="both" to "Remove="uninstall" and I still get the same error when I try to uninstall the service.

Comment: Can you give more details from your installation/uninstallation log? run msiexe using /l*v MyLogFile.txt. I need details about the actual command line that's being run by wix to install and uninstall the service.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to specify your windows user account.

```
<u:User Id="UpdateUserLogonAsService" UpdateIfExists="yes" CreateUser="no" Name="[USERNAME]" LogonAsService="yes" RemoveOnUninstall="no"/>
                <ServiceInstall 
                      Id="ServiceInstaller" 
                      Name="$(var.Name)"
                      Type="ownProcess"
                      DisplayName="$(var.Name)"
                      Description="The description."
                      Start="auto"
                      ErrorControl="normal"
                      Account='[USERNAME]'
                      Password='[PASSWORD]'/>
```